# Match partial text string (90%) two column in two different sheet

Tags: excel, string, vba, match, partial

I'm trying to match (90%) partial text string from a sheet column to another sheet column and bring end result to the master sheet column.
I found a VBA solution but I have some problems with that.
1) it's matching exact text
2) finding a problem to match two different sheet columns.

Please help me to sort this out.

```
Sub lookup()
Dim TotalRows As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

'Copy lookup values from sheet1 to sheet3
Sheets("BANK STATEMENT ENTRY").Select
TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Range("F3:F" & TotalRows).Copy Destination:=Sheets("TEST").Range("A1")

'Go to the destination sheet
Sheets("TEST").Select

For i = 1 To TotalRows
    'Search for the value on sheet2
    Set rng = Sheets("INFO").UsedRange.Find(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    'If it is found put its value on the destination sheet
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Cells(i, 2).Value = rng.Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: what should a "90% match" look like?

Comment: senthuran = 90% * mr. W.Y. senthuran  ? try to use autofilter to compare text roots

Comment: sorry, don't get you. you may add some shots to your post

Comment: Hi there,I receive payment reference from bank downloads ,so i would like to match those reference to my supplier list to allocate the payments but refrence are not exactly same as supplier list. that can be change i tried few matching options but those are not accurate even 60 % thats why I mentioned as atleast 90 %.i want to resolve with a button click thats all.many Thanks

Comment: maybe you're after some fuzzy logic algorithms. you may search SO for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a text mining project and I know you cannot use that approach, you have to break the strings into substrings and then analyze them. It will be a whole project, but you are lucky since I did it for you.

Let's simplify the problem and say that you have two ranges of strings and you want to find every similar strings between two groups. Also, you want to have a tolerance to minimize the matching pairs.

Assume ABCDE and 12BCD00. They have B, C, D, BC, CD and BCD in common. So the longest common substring is BCD which is 3 characters: 3/length of ABCDE(5) will be 60% similarity with the first string and 3/7=43% similarity. So if you can get a list of all those common substrings among all the strings in two ranges you can come up with a better list to filter and get what you want.

I wrote a bunch of functions. To use it easily, just copy and paste both groups of strings in one sheet and generate the final report on the same sheet too to understand how it works.

Function FuzzyFind, finds all of the common substrings and gives you 1st string from Group1/range1, 2nd string from group2/range2, common substring and percentages of similiarity for both strings. The good thing is you can tell the function how small you want your substrings e.g. in the previous example, if you say iMinCommonSubLength=3, it will only give you BCD, if you say iMinCommonSubLength=2 it will give you  BC, CD and BCD and so on.

Use function Main. I also included a Test sub.

**Functions:**

```
Sub TestIt()
    Call Main(ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10"), ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10"), 4, ActiveSheet.Range("D1"))
End Sub

Sub Main(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, iMinCommonSubLength As Integer, Optional rngReportUpperLeftCell As Range)
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim rngReport As Range

    If rngReport Is Nothing Then Set rngReport = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    arr = FuzzyFind(rng1, rng2, iMinCommonSubLength)
    Set rngReport = rngReportUpperLeftCell.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2))

    rngReport.Value = arr
    rngReport.Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
    rngReport.Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@"
    rngReport.Columns(3).NumberFormat = "@"
    rngReport.Columns(4).NumberFormat = "0%"
    rngReport.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "0%"
End Sub

Function GetCharacters(str As String) As Variant
    Dim arr() As String
    ReDim arr(Len(str) - 1)
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        arr(i - 1) = Mid$(UCase(str), i, 1)
    Next
    GetCharacters = arr
End Function


Function GetIterations(iStringLength As Integer, iSubStringLength As Integer) As Integer

    If iStringLength >= iSubStringLength Then
        GetIterations = iStringLength - iSubStringLength + 1
    Else
        GetIterations = 0
    End If
End Function


Function GetSubtrings(str As String, iSubLength As Integer) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant

    count = GetIterations(Len(str), iSubLength)
    ReDim arr(1 To count)

    For i = 1 To count
        arr(i) = Mid(str, i, iSubLength)
    Next i

    GetSubtrings = arr()
End Function

Function GetLongestCommonSubStrings(str1 As String, str2 As String, iMinCommonSubLeng As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLongestPossible As Integer
    Dim iShortest  As Integer

    Dim arrSubs() As Variant

    Dim arr1() As Variant
    Dim arr2() As Variant

    ReDim arrSubs(1 To 1)

    'Longest possible common substring length is the smaller string's length
    iLongestPossible = IIf(Len(str1) > Len(str2), Len(str2), Len(str1))

    If iLongestPossible < iMinCommonSubLeng Then
        'MsgBox "Minimum common substring length is larger than the shortest string." & _
        '   " You have to choose a smaller common length", , "Error"
    Else
        'We will try to find the first match of common substrings of two given strings, exit after the first match
        For i = iLongestPossible To iMinCommonSubLeng Step -1
            arr1 = GetSubtrings(str1, i)
            arr2 = GetSubtrings(str2, i)
            ReDim arrSubs(1 To 1)
            arrSubs = GetCommonElement(arr1, arr2)

            If arrSubs(1) <> "" Then Exit For 'if you want JUST THE LONGEST MATCH, comment out this line
        Next i
    End If

    GetLongestCommonSubStrings = arrSubs
End Function

Function GetCommonElement(arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim arr() As Variant

    count = 1
    ReDim arr(1 To count)

    For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            If arr1(i) = arr2(j) Then
                ReDim Preserve arr(1 To count)
                arr(count) = arr1(i)
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    GetCommonElement = arr
End Function

Function FuzzyFind(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, iMinCommonSubLength As Integer) As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arrSubs As Variant
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim cell1 As Range
    Dim cell2 As Range
    Dim rngReport  As Range
    Dim arr() As Variant 'array of all cells that are partially matching, str1, str2, common string, percentage

    count = 1
    ReDim arr(1 To 5, 1 To count)

    For Each cell1 In rng1
        str1 = UCase(CStr(cell1.Value))
        If str1 <> "" Then
            For Each cell2 In rng2
                str2 = UCase(CStr(cell2.Value))
                If str2 <> "" Then
                    ReDim arrSubs(1 To 1)
                    arrSubs = GetLongestCommonSubStrings(str1, str2, iMinCommonSubLength)
                    If arrSubs(1) <> "" Then
                        For i = 1 To UBound(arrSubs)
                            arr(1, count) = cell1.Value
                            arr(2, count) = cell2.Value
                            arr(3, count) = arrSubs(i)
                            arr(4, count) = Len(arrSubs(i)) / Len(str1)
                            arr(5, count) = Len(arrSubs(i)) / Len(str2)
                            count = count + 1
                            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To 5, 1 To count)
                        Next i
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell2
        End If
    Next cell1

    FuzzyFind = TransposeArray(arr)

End Function


Function TransposeArray(arr As Variant) As Variant
   Dim arrTemp() As Variant
   ReDim arrTemp(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1))
   For a = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
     For b = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arrTemp(a, b) = arr(b, a)
     Next b
   Next a
   TransposeArray = arrTemp
End Function
```

Don't forget to clear the sheet before generating new reports. Insert a table and use its autofilter to easily filter your stuff.

last but not least, don't forget to click on the check mark to announce this as the answer to your question.

Comment: Hi ,first of all thanks for the long code, I think the code will work but my statement in "bank statement entry" sheet "f3:f310", & matching supplier list is in "info"sheet "a2:a210", end matching need to be in "bank statement entry" sheet column "AF". kindly guide me with full code. Many Thanks again in advance.

Comment: check this pic for ref

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why you exactly want to achieve. The codes I gave you will do that for you I am sure of it, but you cannot expect to fine tune it for a specific address or sheet name you have. The best is to copy all the data you need in one place and then let the code do the work for you and then you pick any part of that you want and go back to you sheets and place them in there. BTW, there is no picture attached. You can post an example so that I can give you the direction how to use the code to generate what you need

Comment: Hi lbo,please see the picture I have added where the error coming from .I did copy and pasted on a new work book but still its giving some error.

Comment: I managed to see the picture even though its resolution was not high enough, but it does not show what error you are getting. Can you give us some of the data you need to find matches so that I can run on my side and show you how to use it? the best is a workbook so that you can attach and I will review it for you

Comment: Hi Ibo,I didnt hear anything from you, any luck ? or may be Im troubling you a lot. pls see the added lines in main question as you requested.kindly give me some idea.

Comment: senthuran, I already asked for sample data so that I can show you how to use the code. Just to simplify the problem, for now, keep all the data in one sheet, columns A and B. If you can copy some sample data in columns A and B of a worksheet and attach it, then I can fit the code so that you can see how it works

Comment: Hi ibo, thanks for the prompt email and please see the link below to get the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/cckbux8jh2xw9df/test.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: @senthuran There was a mistake in copy pasting all the functions and somehow one function was copied partially, sorry for that. I corrected the answer and also I corrected on your file. I ran a test also and I could see you have strings that are 2 characters. They will be a problem to analyze. I suggest you never choose less than 4 for the minimum common substring length. To run, simply run TestIt. You can play with the parameters to get what you want. Download the workbook from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4k8ybkk2e23m6ih/test.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Hi ibo,this is perfectly work fantastic, I dont know how to Thank enough to you.you saved most of my side work Imanualy do,one think Im not clear yet tht 1)do I need to Clear table format every time? 2) why that filters go so many rows?kindly let me know nd  I ll close this case as answered.thanks Again nd Happy New Year.

Comment: Hi ibo, I have tryed several ways to change one reference to one match >75% probability then I can look up that to my main sheet that was my intention but it didnt work. is there any way? Many Thanks

Comment: @senthuran Do not focus much on the match percentage. If you exclude strings with less than 4 characters from the comparison lists, then you can get better results to visually go through them to extract what you need. The program cannot do everything for you and at the end you have to make a decision. Also, when you generated the results, go to the report sheet, click on the data, INSERT > INSERT TABLE and use autofilter to sort the percentages Z-A and you can scan the result a lot faster. Don't forget to mark this as the answer (checkmark) please ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot ibo for the feed back.